# Encountered two children with the same key Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map an array of objects (city names) into ANTD's select component.

```
<Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label="City" hasFeedback >
   {getFieldDecorator('city', {
      rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select your city!',}],
      initialValue: this.state.city})(
    <Select
     showSearch
     placeholder="Please select a city"
     optionFilterProp="children"
     filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
    >
  {cities.map(r =>
   <Option key={`${r.lat}`} value={`${r.name}`}>{`${r.name}`}</Option>
   )}
    </Select>
 )}
</Form.Item>
```

this is how the data (cities) looks like [image: cities data] I am clueless as to how I should use the data inside of the `Options`. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using **latitude** for the key, latitude can be same so try using a combination of **latitude** and **name**, this will make it unique.

```
 <Form.Item {...formItemLayout} label="City" hasFeedback >
   {getFieldDecorator('city', {
      rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select your city!',}],
      initialValue: this.state.city})(
    <Select
     showSearch
     placeholder="Please select a city"
     optionFilterProp="children"
     filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
    >
  {cities.map((r,index) =>
   <Option key={`${r.lat}${r.lng}${r.name}${index}`} value={`${r.name}`}>{`${r.name}`}</Option>
   )}
    </Select>
 )}
</Form.Item>
```

*Edit*: could exist two places with the same latitude and name (in a large and weird list, but can happen :-/ ). You should try to create the most unique key, something like:

```
key={`${r.lat}${r.lng}${r.name}`}
```

Comment: i've tried many combinations, including yours, but the problem persist.

Comment: is there a possibility in your data to have lat, long and name same?

Comment: @HafizHanif I have edited the answer, please include the index also, try this

Comment: I've tried that, not working either. Still outputting the same error. i can't understand why.

Comment: I have tried so many combinations, but couldn't get it to work. is there a possibility that the long array causing this?

Comment: Can you console.log the key inside the map, please comment what you get in console.log

Comment: Also can you create a code sample of github or code pen, will help me get a fix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186597/discussion-between-praveen-rao-chavan-g-and-hafiz-hanif).